# cookie wont unset

Tags: php, cookies, unset

I am unable to get the cookie to unset.

cookie set: (id, alias)

```
setcookie("id",$data['id'], time()+3600*24*30);
setcookie("alias",$this->nombre, time()+3600*24*30);
```

cookies unset? (id, alias)

```
setcookie("id","-1",time()-315360000);
setcookie("alias","",time()-315360000);
unset($_COOKIE['id']);       // additional, but still no..
unset($_COOKIE['alias']);    //    "            "
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `unset()` unsets PHP variables; `setcookie()` is a header directive for sending a small text packet to the browser.

Comment: Are they sent from the same domain and directory? You're not setting a domain and directory explicitly, so that could be the source of the problem.

Comment: that was it, we had a long chat in the first answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, I created this test:

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo '<pre>';

setcookie("id","0001", time()+3600*24*30);
setcookie("alias","name", time()+3600*24*30);

print_r($_COOKIE);

if ($_COOKIE['id'] || $_COOKIE['alias']) {
    setcookie("id","-1",time()-315360000);
    setcookie("alias","",time()-315360000);
}

print_r($_COOKIE);

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

On the first load, it outputs:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

On reload:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 0001
    [alias] => name
)
Array
(
    [id] => 0001
    [alias] => name
)
```

On second reload:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

So it appears your code is resetting the cookie on the roundtrip.

**EDIT**

The following:

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo '<pre>';

setcookie("id","0001", time()+3600*24*30);
setcookie("alias","name", time()+3600*24*30);

print_r($_COOKIE);

if ($_COOKIE['id'] || $_COOKIE['alias']) {
    setcookie("id","-1",time()-315360000);
    setcookie("alias","",time()-315360000);
    unset($_COOKIE['id']);
    unset($_COOKIE['alias']);
}

print_r($_COOKIE);

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Will either print:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

Or will print:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 0001
    [alias] => name
)
Array
(
)
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/cookies.php (hit reload a few times)

If you need to tell the browser to forget the cookie, use `setcookie()` with the time set back in time (I use at least 24 hours). If you need the `$_COOKIES` array to forget the value, use `unset()`.

**EDIT**

There are two possible issues contributing here, one a subdomain mismatch on the cookie, and a path accessibility problem.

For instance...

If the url the visitor accessed was on a directory different from where the url that attempts to reset the cookie, you need to set the cookie with a path that will allow that cookie to be accessed (and reset) by other paths.

```
setcookie('my', 'cookie', time()+3600, '/');
```

Or to allow for paths contained within a subdirectory...

```
setcookie('my', 'cookie', time()+3600, '/my/path/');
```

If the url the visitor accessed was a subdomain (including www), but you want the cookie to be accessible to all subdomains, you need to give a wildcard to setcookie.

```
setcookie('my', 'cookie', time()+3600, '/', '.example.com');
```

Will allow urls from www.example.com, my.example.com, and sub.example.com to access and reset the cookie. Obviously, at this point too your path considerations need to be taken into account, since for a subdomain argument, you will need to include a path. `/` selects all subdirectories on the url, and `.` before the domain selects subdomains (although sub.sub.domains, I'm not sure).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: If you've only just sent the headers, it won't appear in the `$_COOKIE` array, since that's a request array. Only on subsequent loads will that `$_COOKIE` array be set.

Comment: Of course (see my comment below the question). I'm thinking the OP is not considering the roundtrip, and is not understanding what unset does. Or are you getting at something else?

Comment: i think i understand you, but i don't know what to do next... :?

Comment: If you're trying to cancel out the cookie on the browser, your `setcookie()` is going to accomplish that. If you need to unset the cookie during the same request, use unset to affect the local `$_COOKIE` array.

Comment: Also, keep in mind you can't use `setcookie()` if you've outputting anything (including whitespace) to the browser. There may be a warning you may not be seeing, if you have `error_reporting()` turned off.

Comment: if you check my question, you will see i am already using unset :(

so we have the same head("Location: where"), problem here (if I understood)...

Comment: I think you need to explain more about the problem you're experiencing. Are you getting an error? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @Toni you didn't answer my question: Are these calls being made from the same directory? ie, are both being set from example.com/foo? or is one example.com/bar'

Comment: @Toni - Adding to yc's comment on the path (default is to set a cookie to be valid only for the current directory), a cookie set from www.example.com and example.com will be treated as separate domains unless the cookie has an argument passed to the `setcookie()` function specifying `.example.com` (note the first period). http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: I set the cookies in different URL but in same directory; so setCookie($name,$value,$time,'/') would do?

Comment: You mean a different subdomain, such as `www.example.com` versus `my.example.com`?

Comment: Noo! just i Set cookies in a example.com/sesion.php and y unset in example.com/?params

Comment: See my edit. I'm still not sure what the exact problem is you're having. Are you having the problem within your PHP code, in the browser, or something else? Also, you cannot reset cookies from other domains than the one the user is accessing (in case you're trying).

Comment: man you are quick! ok, lets say i have htacces redirected wwww.example.com to example.com, so there is not www. for sure. adding '/' worked :D. really, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

How about setting the time to an hour back, rather than that large number?

```
setcookie("alias", "", time()-3600);
```

Comment: this is how I always have done it, everything I've ever read has used an hour as the end all be all of what to set it back by

Comment: I don't think this is any different from the `setcookie()` example the OP uses in the question, where the time is put back ten years, and there's anything magic about one hour (especially when a time zone change could obviate that).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the 'very large number'; it coincides with a decade, which PHP should be able to handle just fine.